# major wobble on my rigged cat

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

I have a cat model that I have sculpted and rigged. He is a pretty fat cat, in between realistic and cartoonish. I made the legs kind of short and not anatomically correct. When I do the walk cycle everything works fine but his belly mesh wobbles way to much. I have tried everything that I can think of to reduce the wobble. I have tried weight painting. I brought down the bones for legs to match with legs. Body looks kind of like a balloon, (that is the way I want it). Some wobble would be good but looks ridicules. I have tried constraints but end up with other problems. I been at blender for a while but haven't done a lot of characters as of yet. I am really desperate to finish this character and start on others for my cartoon I am working on. I would be really grateful for any help or suggestions, good tutorials etc. Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what is wrong. Some pictures, or shared blend file can help people to understand the problem better. ( https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ )

Comment: how do I add a picture?

Comment: I didn't know how to upload my pictures without using the answer box, so below is the answer but pictures showing the issue that I am having.

Comment: edit your question, and in the editor window (above the text area) there would be an image button (Ctrl+G).

Comment: I spent a lot of time researching and found no answers. I finally found a solution, but not after hours of experimenting, why do I get negitave points? I asked the question the best I knew how.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a fix to my problem, posted picture just incase someone else has the same problem with a character. I basically added bones to areas that what distorting more than I cared for. The rig is complex (blenders own rig) but I like it. I tried resizing bones and adding sub dividing bones that only caused more problems. So I finally thought adding to breast bones and placing them in areas that caused to much mesh deform. I also did the same for torso and made two sub bones from it. also from the torso bone a stomach bone. stomach does not deform at all any more when animating but I can use it manually if I want. [image]

Comment: adding bones helps to automatic weights assigning. But there is better way - mastering the weight painting. It gives you better control of how the mesh follows the bones. Some fine tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuunjITq2e0 )

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking for good weight painting, tried it on this character but caused more problems instead of fixing the issues I had, but I am going watch this video link  you gave me. I definitely want to understand weight painting better.

Comment: Definitely, it will pay back on your next characters. There are some not obvious things in weight painting that are essential to be aware of for good results. I myself got a lot from this guy's videos. Good luck. Btw, nice cat. Like the one that meows on my kitchen. :-)